# Java, Mapstruct cast an object with string based accessor

Tags: java, mapping, atg, mapstruct

I have an interface called RepositoryItem that I want to cast to different domain objects using MapStruct. 
The RepositoryItem has one method getPropertyValue(String) that returns an Object which I then have to cast to the destination type. For example:

```
RepositoryItem item = userRepository.getUser("some_id");
String name = (String)item.getPropertyValue("name");
```

Properties can be primitive types as well as other RepositoryItems. There would be multiple mappers all using RepositoryItem as source and some domain class as destination.
Can I generate a mapper for this using MapStruct, is that even doable?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible within MapStruct. MapStruct provides type safe mappings and does not provide a way to map in such a generic way.

There is already a similar feature request ([#1218](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1218)) which is for extracting properties from a `Map`